# magrittr and date objects

Tags: r, magrittr

I just noticed that when I subtract two dates from one another and then try to cast to to a numeric value with magrittr (`%>%`) I get a date, where as if I simply wrap the date difference in `as.numeric()` I get the number of days difference as a numeric value. See the simple example below:

```
## version 1
as.Date("2014-10-10") - as.Date("2014-10-1") %>% as.numeric
## return value -->  "1970-01-10"

## version 2 (returning the value that I actually want)
as.numeric(as.Date("2014-10-10") - as.Date("2014-10-1"))
## return value --> 9
```

While this isn't a big deal here, I would like to understand why this is happening to be able to predict other (for me unexpected) behaviors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, without extra brackets, pipe is computed 1st, then subtraction.

`(as.Date("2014-10-10") - as.Date("2014-10-1")) %>% as.numeric`

Comment: sorry, so why are the extra parenthesis needed? I would have thought that everything before the pipe is passed to as.numeric?

Comment: I couldn't exactly why it is needed, but I would want it to behave this way.

Comment: @zx8754 thanks. This still makes me a bit nervous about unexpected outputs using pipes. Perhaps someone else has a better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

An "all-in `magrittr` solution" also works. Given the recent, sharp increase in the use of pipe operators, quite a few people have commented that an excessive exposure to pipe operators (and aliases) may hurt their eyes. Thus the spoiler block.

> as.Date("2014-10-10") %>%
> subtract(as.Date("2014-10-1")) %>%
>   as.numeric

```
# [1] 9
```

Comment: Why not just use `%>%` vs "`forward pipe operator`" (and, why the "spoiler" block?)

Comment: @Henrik fixed the pipes, it needed extra spaces after the pipes to indicate new line.

Answer (score 0):

I particularly find the naming of operations in magrittr very annoying. In the given example, I would use the [bizarro pipe](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/12/magrittrs-doppelganger/), works like a charm

```
library(magrittr)
as.Date("2014-10-10") - as.Date("2014-10-1") %>% as.numeric
## [1] "1970-01-10"
as.Date("2014-10-10") - as.Date("2014-10-1") ->.; as.numeric(.)
## [1] 9
```

Going even further, while you'd need 3 pipes to get the week difference in the following example (I don't like the parenthesis solution that @zx8754 presented because I think it defeats the purpose of using pipes in the first place), you could have it with just 1 bizarro.

```
as.Date("2014-10-10") %>% subtract(as.Date("2014-08-1")) %>% as.numeric %>% divide_by(7)
## [1] 10
as.Date("2014-10-10") - as.Date("2014-08-1") ->.; as.numeric(.)/7
## [1] 10
```

I'm not saying that using the bizarro is the solution, I just think that magrittr could be improved, that's all.